# Creating WooCommerce Analytical report with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce, analytics

I just recently moved to WooCommerce platform and need to build SQL in MySQL to run my own analytical reports. For example, I need report that shows total number of sales per sku, per country in the last 30 days. 
I explored tables like 'wp_posts', 'wp_postmeta' and found that most fields from products and orders are record-based, not column based which makes the SQL a little more challenging.

Comment: Not sure I follow :-(

Comment: I want to run report in MySQL Workbench that shows quantity of each product that  was sold last month along with the country where this product was shipped to. The source tables are Wordpress/WooCommerce.

Comment: Answer is in the question, so it is no longer a question.

Comment: @Jason, question reopened. Now the OP can move the answer from the question to his own answer post. Max, could you rollback your changes in the question and post your solution as an answer post, please ?

Answer (score 5):

Finally built the SQL by myself. Hope it will be useful for other WooCommerce users who don't want to use analytical out-of-the box solutions or need custom reporting.

```
SELECT 
    sku, count(1)
FROM 
    wp_woocommerce_order_items oi, -- orders table
    wp_posts p, -- woocommerce use posts to keep metadata on the order
    wp_postmeta pm, -- we use this table to filter the completed orders
    wp_postmeta pm1, -- we use this table again for getting the shipping country info
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim, -- use this table to get product ids from orders
    (SELECT p.id as product_id, meta_value as sku FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta pm  where 
        post_type='product' and post_status='publish' 
        and meta_key='_sku' 
        and p.id=pm.post_id) as sku_table -- building temp sku table from published products that defines relationship between product id and sku
WHERE 
    oim.meta_value=sku_table.product_id AND
    oi.order_id=p.ID AND 
    p.id=pm.post_id AND 
    pm.meta_key='_paid_date' AND  -- here we make sure that the order was completed 
    p.id=pm1.post_id AND 
    order_item_type='line_item' AND -- get only line items but not tax or shipping 
    oi.order_item_id=oim.order_item_id AND
    oim.meta_key='_product_id'  AND
    post_date>'2014-01-01' AND -- limits the report date
    pm1.meta_key='_shipping_country' AND -- get shipping country 
    pm1.meta_value='US' -- limits the country
GROUP BY sku
ORDER BY sku;
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you missed that each line item also has a quantity in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`. So your query is just counting how many orders there are for each SKU and not how many of them were sold.